# What are the considerations: Array of Strings or Array of IP Address Arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, ip-address

Ok I am not sure how to do this as I am trying to teach myself C# and create a program for work at the same time.

I have a list of IP addresses I can either load a text file into the textBox1 on the main screen, type a list of IP addresses in the textbox one line at a time or copy and paste into the textbox.

I want to create a new window and pass the list of IP addresses into an Array with the IP addresses from the list in the textbox upon hitting submit.

Do I want to send the text in the textbox to a string, read it out one line at a time in a loop and put them into the array as strings, and pull them out later as IP addresses.

Or do I want to send the text in the textbox to IPAddress.Parse somehow and create multiple arrays of IP Address arrays.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SCA Site(s) Up Tool" Height="498" Width="321">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please Enter an IP Address for the SCA Site or Sites, below.  One IP Address Per Line." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286"/>
        <Button x:Name="submit_Main" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,426,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="submit_Main_Click"/>

        <Button Content="Open File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,426,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button1_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="365" Margin="10,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286" AcceptsReturn="True" AutoWordSelection="True" AllowDrop="True" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream;

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) !=null)
                {
                    string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
                    textBox1.Text = filetext;
                }
            }
        }

        private void submit_Main_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Open  Second Window
            SecondWindow sec = new SecondWindow();
            sec.Show();
            this.Close();

            //Pass Text of TextBox to String

        }
    }
}
```

<<::EDIT::>>
Taking some direction from Andrei Dvoynos, here is how I finally ended up handling this form after switching from WPF to WinForm.  I am going to leave the List of the List to Form2.

```
        private void Submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//            //Pass Text of TextBox1 to String Array tempStr
            List<IPAddress> addresses = new List<IPAddress>();
            foreach (string input in this.textBox1.Lines)
            {
                IPAddress ip;
                if(IPAddress.TryParse(input,out ip))
                {
                    addresses.Add(ip);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Input malformed: {0} :" + input, input + " Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
            }

//           // Loop through the array and send the contents of the array to debug window. 
//            for (int counter = 0; counter < addresses.Count; counter++)
//           {
//               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(addresses[counter]);
//           }

            //close Form1, open and pass list addresses to Form2
            this.Hide(); 
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(addresses);
            f2.Show();
        }
```

Comment: So you want this program to be flexible enough so you can copy paste a list from an external source, or just type the addresses yourself when just a few?

Comment: I want it flexible enough where if I just have one IP address I can open the program put it in the TextBox and it will submit.

The scope will actually be after getting this list from the or those IP Address(es) I will break the IP address down to drop off the last octet of that IP address and ping 5 different devices at that site within that IP address range.  A router, a switch, two riverbeds, and the server at the site. and have a button go green if each device returns a successful ping, red if it doesn't

Comment: Sounds like a fun project, I would keep it as a `list<string>` as long as possible, but that's only because it looks like you need to manipulate the ip addresses, and I'm not sure how flexible is the `IpAddress` class to do that

Comment: http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/?page_id=60
From what I am reading about it.  the IPAddress Class was made for this type of thing it creates an array of 4, 3 byte variables for the IP address where each 3 byte variable is one octet of the IP address.

The thing I am note sure of yet is getting the information from the textbox into a seperate Array Item for each new line in the textbox.

Comment: You can parse the values of the textbox into a `List<List<IpAddress>>`  so you have for each of the lines you put into the textbox, a list of IpAddresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement it something like this:

```
private void submit_Main_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Open  Second Window
        SecondWindow sec = new SecondWindow();
        sec.Show();
        this.Close();

        //Pass Text of TextBox to String
        List<List<IpAddress>> ipAddresses = new List<List<IpAddresses>>();
        foreach(var line in textbox1.Text.split('\n')//Not 100% sure this would work, but give it a try :)
        {
            var list = new List<IpAddress>();
            list.add(IpAddress.parse(replaceLastOctet(line, "125"));
            list.add(IpAddress.parse(replaceLastOctet(line, "120"));
            list.add(IpAddress.parse(replaceLastOctet(line, "115"));
            list.add(IpAddress.parse(replaceLastOctet(line, "110"));
            list.add(IpAddress.parse(replaceLastOctet(line, "105"));
            ipAddresses.Add(list);
        }

    }

    private string replaceLastOctet(string ipAddress, string octet)
    {
       //You can change this function to actually do the parsing and replacing, and return an ipaddress instead of a string
       //TODO: Write the code to do this :)
    }
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do this using WPF instead of Windows Forms?  It appears that the system.windows.controls.textbox doesn't have a Lines Method.

Comment: I did end up giving up on WPF and have converted everything to a Windows Forms Project.

Comment: Lists are a new concept for me, especially a list inside a list, so could anyone suggest a place I can read up on them and how the above code works?

Comment: My bad for using Lines there...it's not really an existing property of the textbox, I was just lazy and didn't code that part, thought you might do it :) Hence my comment at the end of that line...

Comment: As for Lists, they're pretty easy to grasp. It's basically one of many typed collections, meaning that you can only put inside them the type that you declared, as opposed to arrays, where you can put in them any type. You're almost always better off using lists or other type of generic collections, like Dictionary<T,T> instead of plain arrays...you can find a bunch of documentation on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just use `IPAddress.parse`, unless you do not have to separate each IP string,
for example `ipaddress1`, `ipaddress2`, `ipaddress3`, you are probably going to have to do some string manipulation, not to sure on what `IPAddress.parse` does, but if you do not have to manipulate anything then that seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a throw-away, then it doesn't matter. On the other hand, typing strings into text boxes and showing strings in list menus is at the user interaction tier of an *n-tiered* architecture and performing actions on IP addresses is on the application tier. Storing and retrieving the datum is of course on the data tier.

What this means is that converting an input string into an IP address object is essentially boxing the string in terms of the UI tier. In terms of the data tier it is object serialization and deserialization when a datum is needed by the view tier. In other words, storing the input as an IP address object means that every write to the data store requires serialization and that some fraction of reads require deserialization.

On the other hand, storing the input as a string means that only some fraction of the inputs get serialized - those needed by the program as IP addresses and nothing gets deserialized [ever?].

Validation has similar tradeoffs. Storing a string means that the only validation on input is formatting. Storing IP addresses potentially means white/black list validation during input and because often URL's emit different behaviours at different times white/black list validation might be prudent on retrieval. And again this is more of an application tier task than a UI or data storage tier concern.

At the scale where serializing on reads from the data-store affects performance, then there is always the option of caching. But caching, - essentially what storage as an IP-address equates to - early doesn't really appear any obvious benefits that outweigh separation of concerns.

Comment: I think that the validation would be the most important part from this. The other considerations, for such a small app, sound like you're over complicating the problem. Then again, you state that clearly on your first line :)

Comment: @AndreiDvoynos There are three things that can happen to a small app - it can die, stay small or grow. Oak trees grow from tiny acorns. Big balls of mud grow from little balls of mud. It's not as if I am proposing additional code - skipping deserialization may even mean less. What a am proposing is additional thought about the design. Only a little, though, thinking in three tiers is probably enough.